# Openlayers errors with clone and setAnimation

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, openlayers

I am working on this web application, it uses Javascript and Openlayers etc.

I have this block of code that throws errors at me all the time

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
        jQuery(this).restoreRow(lastSel);
        lastSel = id - 1;
    }
    subMarkerArray[id - 1] = reportingAvlMap.bringToFront(subMarkerArray[id - 1]);                         
    latLonPoint.transform(fromProjection, reportingAvlMap.map.baseLayer.projection);
    reportingAvlMap.map.setCenter(latLonPoint, reportingAvlMap.map.zoom);
    subMarkerArray[id - 1].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

    setTimeout(function() {
        subMarkerArray[id - 1].setAnimation(null);
    }, 750);
},
```

The following line

```
var latLonPoint = subMarkerArray[id - 1].attributes.lonlat.clone();
```

Gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined
```

And the following line

```
subMarkerArray[id - 1].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

Gives me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction please?

Comment: It is very hard to tell what might be the problem based on that code sample. You need to provide a jsFiddle of something similar that replicates the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are using OpenLayers. The code sample looks to be entirely Google Maps related?